# How to update Shipping rates using Ajax when cart item is deleted on Checkout-Cart page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, ajax, quote

My Shipping rates are calculated based on item present in cart and now on deletion of item on `Checkout/Cart` page, I need to update the Shipping rates. As of now, **Remove Item** on `Checkout/Cart` page updates the total section but does not refresh the shipping rates. It would be of great help if someone can guide me on how to trigger get shipping rates once item is deleted from cart using Ajax.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you doing well.

**Please try with this JavaScript code.Hope this will help you.**

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'

    ],
    function (quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
       'use strict';

       var processors = [];

       rateRegistry.set(quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey(), null);

       processors.default =  defaultProcessor;
       processors['customer-address'] = customerAddressProcessor;

       var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

       if (processors[type]) {
          processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
       } else {
          processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
       }

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 requirejs([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'
], function(quote, rateRegistry){


    var address = quote.shippingAddress();

    address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();

    rateRegistry.set(address.getKey(), null);
    rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);

    quote.shippingAddress(address);
});
```